# Accessing variables from a struct included in a Class

Tags: c++, class, struct

I have a class, which includes a Struct. I've declared two variables of the given class and I can't access the variables from the struct Variables.
The class:

```
class Game
{
public:
    Game( class MainWindow& wnd );
    Game( const Game& ) = delete;
    Game& operator=( const Game& ) = delete;
    void Go();
private:
    void ComposeFrame();
    void UpdateModel();
    /********************************/
    /*  User Functions              */
    /********************************/
private:
    MainWindow& wnd;
    Graphics gfx;
    /********************************/
    /*  User Variables              */
    int x_mobile, y_mobile;
    bool Collision();
    /********************************/
public:
    struct Bar {
        int speed, start;
        bool pressedDown = false, pressedUp = false;
        int extremitati[108];
    };
    bool Collision(int x, int y, Bar both);
    bool MoveBar(Bar l, Bar r);
    void ConstructBar(Bar l, Bar r);

};
```

And, here I've created two struct variables: 'left' and 'right'. In those struct variables I have a variable called "start", I want to access it, but dosen't work, I don't know exactly how to access them.

```
// objects
Game::Bar left, right;


//

// Bar Objects - Variables
Game::Bar::left.start = 100;
//
```

And, when I'm trying to acccess it, i get this error:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to prefix the variables with a type when you use them in an expression:

```
left.start = 100;
```

... since `left` and `right` are the variable names here.